# Can I use "chosen by the oracles" to increase damage?

Tags: l5r, l5r-4e

I'm using **L5R 4th** Portuguese version (Brazilian).
A player is using the **Chosen by the Oracles** ( *You gain a bonus of +1k1 to
the total of all Ring Rolls using that Ring.* ) advantage to increase the damage of the **The Fires from within** (*The spell has a DR equal to your Fire Ring*) spell.
He has **Fire 4**, so there's **5k5 damage**. Is that valid?

Thanks a lot!

(English is not my first language)

Comment: I will have to double check my L5r book tonight but gut feeling is "yes" (after review I will post an answer)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer; No.

The Spell tells you that it has a Damage Rating (DR) equal to your Fire Ring, meaning that you are making a Damage Roll for the spell, not a Ring Roll.

Check P.80 (or under the **Types of Rolls** section of the book if the Portuguese version has different formatting) and you will find that Damage Rolls and Ring Rolls are treated differently by the game.

Unfortunately there aren't many effects that require Fire Ring rolls to make use of the bonus from Chosen by the Oracles but the bigger part of that advantage should be the implications of being favoured by an agent of the celestial dragons.